# Erro ao VBA para mandar e-mail

Tags: envio-de-email

Boa tarde,

Estou tentando usar a função abaixo, porém quando ele abre o outlook da a seguinte mensagem de erro "Programa tentando enviar e-mail em seu o nome. Se isso for inesperado, clique em negar e verifique se o software antivirus está atualizado.)"

```
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")


OutApp.Session.Logon


Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)


    On Error Resume Next


    With OutMail
       .To = "" '''para quem vai, colocar os destinatários e separar com ;
       .cc = "" '''quem será copiado no e-mail separar com ;
       .BCC = "" ''' com cópia oculta se houver
       .Subject = "" ''' Titulo do e-mail
       .Attachments.Add " " '''colocar o caminho do arquivo se for anexar algo


       '''Aqui é o corpo do e-mail, o que será inserido nele.



       '.Send para enviar direto e .Display para visualizar antes de enviar
       .Send '''ou . Display

    End With





Application.Quit
```